# Injective and quasi injective modules

Tags: injective-module

Definition: An $R$-module $M$ is called quasi-injective module if for every submodule $N$, any $R$-homomorphism $N\to M$ extends to an endomorphism of $M$.

How can I prove that every injective module is quasi-injective ?

Comment: Could you solve the problem with the hint I've done? If yes, would you like to accept the answer to remove the question off the "unanswered queue"? If no, tell me and I'll try to expand the hint to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use the definition of the injectivity in the case of $\iota:N\to M$ being the inclusion.